# Converting a list into a pandas dataframe using keys as column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list in the following format:

```
[{'date': '2019-05-06', 'open': 51.0725, 'high': 52.21, 'low': 50.875, 'close': 52.12, 'volume': 129772452}, 
 {'date': '2019-05-07', 'open': 51.47, 'high': 51.854375, 'low': 50.20625, 'close': 50.715, 'volume': 155054790}, 
 {'date': '2019-05-08', 'open': 50.475, 'high': 51.335, 'low': 50.4375, 'close': 50.725, 'volume': 105358016}, 
 {'date': '2019-05-09', 'open': 50.1, 'high': 50.42, 'low': 49.165, 'close': 50.18, 'volume': 139634430}]
```

How do I store this list as a pandas dataframe with the keys **('date','open','high','low','close','volume')** as the column names and the values as records in the dataframe?

Comment: Have you even searched for this ?

Comment: Think of the most obvious method of converting data to a DataFrame.  That's how you do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pd.DataFrame([{'date': '2019-05-06', 'open': 51.0725, 'high': 52.21, 'low': 50.875, 'close': 52.12, 'volume': 129772452}, 
 {'date': '2019-05-07', 'open': 51.47, 'high': 51.854375, 'low': 50.20625, 'close': 50.715, 'volume': 155054790}, 
 {'date': '2019-05-08', 'open': 50.475, 'high': 51.335, 'low': 50.4375, 'close': 50.725, 'volume': 105358016}, 
 {'date': '2019-05-09', 'open': 50.1, 'high': 50.42, 'low': 49.165, 'close': 50.18, 'volume': 139634430}])
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLKWh.png)